# my app is freezing and it is still runing

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to find this error for a long time. My app is freezing and I don't know where or how and the freezes are some what random and when it does I got this:

```
 Feb 11 12:49:09 MAC.local backboardd[1542] <Error>:__hid_dispatch_pthread_root_queue_create_block_invoke: specific=0x4f3ed50 pthread_self=0xb0115000
```

If someone have an idea how to solve this issue any thing you still need to help please do tell me because I really need to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks like you are creating you own threads & not returning to main_thread. check in your code.

Comment: Click the pause button in XCode, and you will see where it is hanging.